YOTPO how i can reach elements via js
I have yotpo on my website and need to add GTM events so i connected custom js to my yotpo page and trying to do something when i click on button that comes from yotpo. I tried call it by css class. Also tried to add id to element and then do something by id. Id added successfully but it's still doesn't work. Maybe someone knows how to catch click on yotpo elements? Or how can i call yotpo elements properly?
Tried to reach it by css class and by custom id. Expected that when I click on yotpo button then some logic works.

try :  $(document).on('click','<add yotpo button class>',function(){ ... alert('working');});

Already tried this way

https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

// Wait for the document to be fully loaded
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // Use event delegation to handle clicks on dynamically loaded Yotpo buttons
    $(document).on('click', '.yotpo-button-class', function() {
        // Your custom logic here
        console.log('Yotpo button clicked!');
        // Push event to GTM
        window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
        window.dataLayer.push({
            'event': 'yotpoButtonClick',
            'eventCategory': 'Yotpo',
            'eventAction': 'Click',
            'eventLabel': 'Yotpo Button'
        });
    });
});


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
